# How can I include common components when I develop static pages by gulp or other tools

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gulp, gruntjs

If I was developing static pages, just html files and these files may contain common components such as headers or footers...Can I move these components into a separate file and include this file when a page need this component？And if I use gulp's live reload, How can I achieve this? Just like PHP on the server:

```
<?php include xxx ?>
```

Comment: I use `ejs` and gulp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create templates with ejs and generate html files with gulp.

It also supports lesscss compile.

[Starting with templates with ejs and gulp](https://zellwk.com/blog/nunjucks-with-gulp/)